# Swift 4.1 compactMap for lazy collections

Tags: arrays, swift, lazy-initialization, swift4.1

Prior to the Swift 4.1 I used `flatMap` to remove `nil` values from collections. Now this method is deprecated and I need to replace it with `compactMap`. Sometimes I used `flatMap` with lazy collections to optimise my code, like that:

```
let optionalIntegers : [Int?] = [1, 2, nil, 3, 4, nil, nil, 5]
optionalIntegers.lazy.flatMap { $0 }.forEach { print("Item \($0 * 10)") }
```

Will it has the same effect if I will use `compactMap` instead of `flatMap`? In documentation for the method `lazy` I found references to `map` and `filter` only.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, absolutely the same. They just decided to remove the ambiguity of `flatMap` functions and renamed one of them to `compactMap` not to confuse developers.

Here is the proposal: [Introduce Sequence.compactMap(_:)](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0187-introduce-filtermap.md)

> We propose to deprecate the controversial version of a Sequence.flatMap method and provide the same functionality under a different, and potentially more descriptive, name.

[image]